# Can not add windows media player for windows forms in net6.0-windows

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I created a new .NET 6.0 project and copy-pasted my .NET 5 files into it (and made a few changes to use .net6 potential). My project is also using Windows Media Player, which I have to add from COM models. When I try to do it, Visual Studio still fails to compile, because Windows Media Player was not found.

Is there any way to include Windows Media Player or do I have to stay on .NET 5.0?

Comment: What is the "older version" you talk about? .NET Framework 4.x?

Comment: It worked in .net 5